# Delay on button clicks using PhoneGap Developer App

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui

I understand the latest version of Onsen UI has Fastclick built in for increased touch performance. I have been testing using the PhoneGap Developer App and noticed both

```
ng-click="ons.navigator.pushPage('page.html')
```

and

```
ng-click="ons.screen.presentPage('page.html')
```

appears a tad sluggish.

I have tried including "ngTouch" in my main module just in case with no real improvement.

```
var app = angular.module("appName", ['ngTouch', 'onsen.directives']);
```

Is this simply a by-product of using PhoneGap to develop mobile apps? I certainly don't expect the same performance of a true native app, but does anyone know a we can improve the responsiveness just a tad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own directive which handles touchstart event.

```
myApp.directive('onsTouchstart', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('touchstart', function() {
            scope.$apply(attrs['onsTouchstart']);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: I added this code to my project and went through the full build and install on my mobile device via PhoneGap App Build. Both ng-click and ons-touchstart were not slightly unresponsive. (Definitely not the same responsiveness of a true native app). I guess this is just the compromise when developing hybrid apps. If anyone knows of a different way to reduce the lag, please respond/share.

Comment: To clarify, the answer given is indeed is the solution. The lag I was experiencing seems to be the ons.navigator.pushPage() call itself. Onsen UI page transition framework just seems to have a delay.